# Swashbuckler/Swagger 2.0 thinks API controller is an endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

For a project I'm working on, we have an old ASP.NET MVC project, that has had an ASP.NET Framework Web API grafted onto it.

In this project, we have a single version of our API, with each 'version' being its own controller, as below:

`GET https://dev-myradsystem/api/v1/GetUsers`

The controller looks like this:

```
public class V1Controller: ApiController
{
    // Exposes: /api/v1/GetUsers
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponse GetUsers()
    {
        var result = MagicService.GetUsers()
        return new HttpResponse(HttpStatus.OK, result);
    }

    // Exposes: /api/v1/GetUserById/???
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponse GetUserById(string id)
    {
        // ...Essentially the same as above.
    }

    // There's other endpoints, but let's just focus on this for now.
}
```

**NOTE:** Now, you might just be tempted to say, "Aaah, you should just add `[Route(...)]` to your endpoints, or `[RoutePrefix(...)]` to your API Controller!  Well, *we can't do that.*  This project's technology predates the introduction of the Routing attributes, and we're not yet able to upgrade it due to time/duty constraints.

As this is older-style ASP.NET, we made sure that Swagger is not being hindered by the routing system:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // ...Other routes, don't really matter in this context...
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
        routes.IgnoreRoute("swagger/{*any}");  // <-- This is what we added
        routes.MapRoute(                       // <-- Yes, this does coexist with an MVC site
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

After installing Swashbuckler on this web project - with the following SwaggerConfig:

```
public static void Register()
{
    var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .EnableSwagger(c => {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My Rad Web API");
        })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c => {});
}
```

...whenever we attempt to hit `https://dev-myradsystem/swagger`, we get a message like:

`failed to parse JSON/YAML response`

...We also get an internal exception message:

```
Path: /swagger/docs/v1

Message: Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path 'api/V1' and method 'GET'. See the config setting - "ResolveConflictingActions" for a potential workaround

Stack Trace: at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultConflictingActionsResolver(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions) 
at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry) 
at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__4(IGrouping`2 group) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) 
at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String rootUrl, String apiVersion) 
at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

...Now, I know what you're thinking: "Just read the friendly error message!"  However, I can tell you with complete certainty that *this error message is a red herring.*

The problem is NOT that there are multiple `api/V1` operations.  The problem is that, when Swagger is auto-generating the `swagger.json`, the error message above informs us that it's interpreting `/` as the API's `basePath`, `api` as the controller, and `v1` as the action, thus the error message.  *Needless to say, this is very much incorrect.*

While my team has used more recent versions of Swagger with ASP.NET Core, we're finding that older usages of Swagger are, at best, poorly documented.  Which, leads to my question:

**QUESTION:** Assuming a freshly-installed Swashbuckler/Swagger 2.0, in what way can we get our V1 API controller to properly render when we navigate to our `https://dev-myradsystem/swagger/` ?